# How to check if the values in a range, let's say B2:B10 are present in range let's say A2:A6 using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can do the same manually if the range is small. I need the formula if the range is too big to imagine. The result should be in Column C letting me know the values of col B that are present in col A. Can we use look ups, if so, then how so.

[image]

Comment: Try vlookup function in excel: `=VLOOKUP($B2,$A$2:$A$6,1,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `COUNTIF()` like-

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,B2:B10)=0,"Not exist","Exist")
```

For older version of excel try-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$6,0)),"exist","not exist")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `XMATCH()` & `ISNA()` will be relatively fast if using `MS365`

[image: Formula_Solution]

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(ISNA(XMATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$6,0)),"Not Found","Found")
```

---

If you are not using `MS365` then use `MATCH()` with `ISNA()`

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$6,0)),"Not Found","Found")
```